# Rails forward a response as is from an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, response, render

I am making a call to an external API in my controller function.

```
# {root}/some/route
def my_action
  # call to external API
  resp = my_call_to_external_api
end
```

This external API call returns a response 200 and with a body.

I want to forward this response as is as my controllers response when someone hits the route
{root}/some/route.

My response with the current implementation is status 204 with no body. I checked logs and found out that this is because there is nothing to render for my controller action after it calls the external API successfully, hence is is rendering 204 :no_content. 
How would I make sure that my controller action just forwards the response as is that is being received from the external API.

I am new to this, so any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is that an API outside the application? Maybe you could redirect to that route if not. Usualy when you try to do this I would not recommend doing this in the controller. You write a class /module in the lib folder and call that to perform the call process the response and return the result here.

Comment: Yesm the API os outside the application, So, I will not be able to redirect to that route.
I have processed it in another module and call that function in my controller. For simplicity I just have my call mentioned here in the question.
Still, the response is not what I am expecting. I am just expecting it to forward the response as is from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve this was, render the status I received from the response with body parsed from the response.

```
render :ok, json: resp.read_body
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI(YOUR_URL)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

This might solve your problem.